# How to connect oracle database from ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, oracle11g

I am facing an issue in connecting the oracle database from java ee application using hibernate in eclipse. I have the oracle 11g database in local server vm machine. I am not able to connect using the application which is running in ubuntu os and i get an exception like

```
java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at OracleJDBC.main(OracleJDBC.java:29)
```

But when i try the application windows os it work fine.

I checked with the firewall and it is off also, but i am not able to connect the database in ubuntu os.

Is there any other required to configure in the application to connect with the database.

Comment: Your VM network type is NAT and you can ping your local VM?

Comment: This error occurs due to below reasons:- Check the host you are connecting to db.Is it accessible from you ubuntu machine.It could be using the wrong URL

- The wrong port number or IP address (or DNS host name) was used

- The listener is not configured properly

- The listener process (service) is not running.  You can re-start it with the "lsnrctl start".